# Python wildcard matching between two list

Tags: python, list, matching

so I've had this issue in the past where I've needed to do some string matches with parts of strings from one list to another, in the past I've worked the solution in a few ways. Tonight I came up with a solution that works, but I feel that there maybe a more effective way to go about it.

I took a break from a different project to block a bunch of ad domains using my HOST file to speed up the loading of the yahoo finance page.

The result list are the domains that don't match the trusted list.

This code works in python 3.4, so if you've had this issue as well...then I hope this works for you too.

```
def list_exclusion(suspect_list, trusted_list):

    loop_count = len(trusted_list)

    exclusion_list = []
    for domain in suspect_list:

        while loop_count > 0:

            if domain.find(trusted_list[loop_count - 1]) != -1:
                exclusion_list.append(domain)

            loop_count -= 1

        loop_count = len(trusted_list)

    bad_list = []
    for x in suspect_list:
        if x not in exclusion_list:
            bad_list.append(x)

    return bad_list

trusted_list = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yimg.com', 'thomsonreuters.com', 'stackexchange.com']

suspect_list = ['s1.2mdn.net', 'doubleclick.com', 'ads.facebook.com', 'electronics.stackexchange.com']

bad_list = list_exclusion(suspect_list, trusted_list)

for bad_guy in bad_list:
    print(bad_guy)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` operator to do containment check (whether a string is a substring of another string) , and you can use the `any()` function as well (to check whether a any string in a list of strings is a substring of another string. Example -

```
def list_exclusion(suspect_list, trusted_list):
    bad_list = []
    for x in suspect_list:
        if not any((i in x) for i in trusted_list):
            bad_list.append(x)
    return bad_list
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def list_exclusion(suspect_list, trusted_list):
...     bad_list = []
...     for x in suspect_list:
...             if not any((i in x) for i in trusted_list):
...                     bad_list.append(x)
...     return bad_list
...
>>> trusted_list = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yimg.com', 'thomsonreuters.com', 'stackexchange.com']
>>>
>>> suspect_list = ['s1.2mdn.net', 'doubleclick.com', 'ads.facebook.com', 'electronics.stackexchange.com']
>>>
>>> bad_list = list_exclusion(suspect_list, trusted_list)
>>>
>>> for bad_guy in bad_list:
...     print(bad_guy)
...
s1.2mdn.net
doubleclick.com
ads.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return a list comp using `all`:

```
def list_exclusion(suspect_list, trusted_list):
    return [domain for domain in suspect_list if all(domain.find(d) == -1 for d in trusted_list)]
```

Or use `in` although it won't really be any faster and may even be slower:

```
def list_exclusion(suspect_list, trusted_list):
    return [domain for domain in suspect_list if all(d not in domain for d in trusted_list)]
```